# maven-assembly-plugin run multiple times, configure to run only once

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

Small question regarding maven-assembly-plugin please.

I am currently configuring as follow:

```
    <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>build</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <archive>
                                <manifest>
                                    <mainClass>my.Main</mainClass>
                                </manifest>
                            </archive>
                            <descriptorRefs>
                                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                            </descriptorRefs>
                            <finalName>${project.artifactId}-mymain</finalName>
                            <outputDirectory>./</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

This has nothing special, copied from the official website on how to configure.

Now, we use a CI tool, the CI tool, which we do not control, will run the following steps (we cannot change it)

```
compile:
maven  -DskipTests clean package

test
maven verify

stage
maven -skipTests deploy
```

It will run the three steps separately, again, nothing I can do about it.

Now, the thing it, it seems with the current `maven-assembly-plugin` as configured above, the uber jar is built once each stage, resulting in a total of 3 jars being built.

How to configure the plugin, to avoid being built and rebuilt, hoping to be built only in one specific phase please?

Thank you

Comment: Running the steps as you mentioned does not make sense for Maven because a lot of steps are repeated. That's wasting of time and resources...Only `mvn clean deploy` is correct and the rest can removed. Furthermore the configuration contains things which are not correct like `<finalName>..</finalName>` which does not exist in maven-assembly-plugin and the `<outputDirectory>..</outputDirectory>` shouldn't be changed.

Comment: Also the execution three times is exactly the reason for creating the jars three times. The simplest solution to prevent built three times is as mentioned only execution `mvn clean deploy`...

Comment: Totally agree with you @khmarbaise, I wish it can do only one execution, the execution of ```mvn clean deploy```, as I mentioned in the original question, the CI service does not allow us to do such (removing the ```finalName``` and ```outputDirectory ``` does not help) What would be a way to prevent the duplicates build, knowing the CI service cannot be changed please?

Comment: It does not make sense not to change CI service because it's wasting a lot of resources and time...which is also the root cause of the problem.

Comment: Again totally agree with you, I wish I could change CI service, but it is a provider. Again, I fully agree with you, the CI provider is very bad, let's change it. I wish I could, in the meantime, is there a technical way we can achieve this by configuring the plugin itself?

Comment: Technically you can create a profile which is activated only in a particular state of your CI ....which means you have to change the CI setup (add `-Pxyz`)...which you already mentioned is not possible. You could try to change the phase to which the assembly-plugin is bound to (from `<phase>package</phase>` to `<phase>install</phase>` but I'm not sure if this will work correctly(I except other issues). The root cause is the wrong configuration in the CI setup. That's it...everything else is a Hack which will cause further issues in the future. I strongly discourage that path!

Comment: Hey @khmarbaise, it actually worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @khmarbaise, this `<phase>install</phase>` works. All the credit to him, thank you